# Why does Google Analytics Ecommerce reports show a quantity of 4 for every transaction that should have a quantity of 1?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

Why does Google Analytics Ecommerce reports show a quantity of 4 for every transaction that should have a quantity of 1?

I am only calling _trackTrans() once and my system is set up that a user cannot refresh the receipt page. I have confirmed that the data I am sending to Google includes the proper quantity (which is typically 1).

Comment: I don't know how you expect to get any help when you don't post any code or site to test or anything... But in any case, if you are 100% certain there is no bug on your end, then that means there's a bug on GA's end. Unfortunately, I have not seen nor heard of a bug from GA about this. Not saying it is impossible for GA to be bugged, but given that there are millions of people using GA, I'm more inclined to believe there is a bug on your end.

Comment: Your question is vague and its obvious you have something wrong in the code. Otherwise, you will be seeing quantity 1 as you said